# Testcafe wont recognise React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to run my first testcafe test but it's proving arduous.

> testcafe -e chrome client/routes/Lookup/components/testcafe/lookup-test.js

```
SyntaxError: client/routes/Lookup/components/Lookup.js: Unexpected token (60:8)
  58 |     if (error.status && error.status !== 404) {
  59 |       return (
> 60 |         <NetworkIssues code={error.status} />
     |         ^
  61 |       );
  62 |     }
  63 |
at Object.<anonymous> (client/routes/Lookup/components/testcafe/lookup-test.js:1:1)
```

lookup-test.js

```
import Lookup from '../Lookup';
import React from 'react';
import { waitForReact } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';


fixture('Lookup Component').page('http://localhost:3000/web/lookup').beforeEach(async () => {
  await waitForReact();
});

test('foo', async (x) => {
  await x
    .typeText('customerName', '07450118811')
    .expect('customerName.value').contains('07450118811');
});
```

My code doesn't have any errors. It compiles and works fine and passes all my jest and enzyme unit testing. But I can't find any guidance online for this. As you can see the ignore errors flag is used to no avail.

Cheers.

Comment: you can try to use this option as a hacky workaround - https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors

as another idea(never used testcafe tbh), you can give a try to `ReactSelector('<target component>');` and then use this selector as the first argument inside `typeText`. Similar is done here https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors if you search for `typeText`

Comment: Please send me a link to your web page or create a similar online example so that I can check the issue locally.

Answer (score 1):

When you start TestCafe, all your test code is transpiled as a first step before execution. What is executed is the result of this transpilation process and not your original source code, even if your code is pure JavaScript.

The imported file `client/routes/Lookup/components/Lookup.js` is a JSX file, and since it is imported in the TestCafe code, il will be first transpiled to javascript before starting test execution.

The TestCafe transpilation process (at the time of writing - it may change in the future) is not configured to handle JSX files.

Therefore, you cannot import files that cannot be transpiled into pure JS by TestCafe.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting this out

```
//import Lookup from '../Lookup'
```

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe can't handle JSX outside of class components.  If you are using react, and create a function that returns JSX, testCafe will throw up on it.  You can resolve it by just creating a new class component instead.  see [TestCafé + React JSX error (unexpected Token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566816/testcaf%c3%a9-react-jsx-error-unexpected-token) for more details.